# How to use italic "N" on tbl_summary header {gtsummary}

Tags: r, gtsummary, italic

I would like to change `tbl_summary` header to "*n* = xx" instead of default "N = xx".
I understand that this could be modified by using `modify_header`, like:

```
modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, N = {n}")
```

However, I cannot figure out how to make the N italicized,
since N is already in the parenthesis to make it character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any markdown syntax in the headers. In the example you provided, the double stars indicate bold. Use single stars to italicize the n. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")

trial %>%
  select(age, grade, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, *n* = {n}")
```

[image]

To use markdown syntax in the body of a table, you can convert to gt and use the `gt::fmt_markdown()` function.

```r
library(gtsummary)

lm(mpg ~ factor(cyl) + am, mtcars) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(
    include = c(adj.r.squared, statistic, p.value), 
    label = list(statistic ~ "*F*", 
                 adj.r.squared ~ "*Adjusted R\U00B2*", 
                 p.value ~ "*p*")) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::fmt_markdown(columns = label)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do the same when `add_glance_table` ?
For example, `add_glance_table(include = c(adj.r.squared, statistic, p.value), label = list(statistic ~ "*F*", adj.r.squared ~ "Adjusted $R^2$", p.value ~ "*p*"))`
doesn't work.

Comment: Post updated with another example

Comment: Thank you very much! You are a life saver..